# javascript mouseout function flickering

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a mouse in and out effect that shows and disappears DIV's according to the mouse function. I've successfully done this, but the mouseout function flickers on and off when im inside the div instead of staying on.

Heres my sample code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Kow Your Face</title>
<style>
#face {
    background-image: url(face.png);
    width: 262px;
    height: 262px;
    }
#lefteye {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 69px;
    left: 59px;
    }
#righteye {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 41px;
    left: 167px;
    }
#mouth {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 84px;
    left: 114px;
    }           
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="face">
        <div id="lefteye" onMouseOver="getElementById('lefteye').style.visibility='hidden'; getElementById('lefteyedes').style.visibility='visible';" onMouseOut="getElementById('lefteye').style.visibility='visible'; getElementById('lefteyedes').style.visibility='hidden';">
        </div>
        <div id="righteye" onMouseOver="getElementById('righteye').style.visibility='hidden'; getElementById('righteyedes').style.visibility='visible';" onMouseOut="getElementById('righteye').style.visibility='visible'; getElementById('righteyedes').style.visibility='hidden';">
        </div>
        <div id="mouth" onMouseOver="getElementById('mouth').style.visibility='hidden'; getElementById('mouthdes').style.visibility='visible';" onMouseOut="getElementById('mouth').style.visibility='visible'; getElementById('mouthdes').style.visibility='hidden';">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lefteyedes" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <p>Left Eye</p>
    </div>
    <div id="righteyedes" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <p>Right Eye</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mouthdes" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <p>Mouth</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which mouseout event? All of them or 1 in particular

Comment: All of the mouse events

Comment: sorry for 20 questions...so it's not that the mouseout function flickers on and off, it's that the divs bound to a specific mouseout event flicker on and off, correct? Does this happen when the mouse moves inside one of the divs only or even when the mouse is stationary inside one of the divs?

Comment: only when the mouse moves, and both flicker on and off the mouseout function and div, but only when the mouse is moving within the Div. Thanks for taking the time to really try and help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById` instead of just `getElementById` and you can use `this` keyword to refer to the current element:

```
<div id="lefteye" onMouseOver="this.style.visibility='hidden'; document.getElementById('lefteyedes').style.visibility='visible';" onMouseOut="this.style.visibility='visible'; document.getElementById('lefteyedes').style.visibility='hidden';">
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, you made my code easier to read, but It still flickers while in the element.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your onmouseout function is being repeatedly called "onmousemove"...this solution should help you suppress the onmouseout function being repeatedly called. I've rewritten your code a little to help make it easier to enforce changes later (illustrated with one of the onmouseover/onmouseout pairs)...give this a shot:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function leftEyeVisibility(vis1, vis2) {
      //this function should work for the left eye when the left eye is hidden (lefteyedes is visible) and the mouse is moving over (or not moving at all) the hidden left eye div but has not moused out of it
      var dg = document.getElementById("lefteye");
      var divStyle = window.getComputedStyle(dg, "");

      var mousePosition = function (e) {
          var xCoord = e.pageX;
          var yCoord = e.pageY;
          return xCoord + "," + yCoord;
      }

      var positionArray = mousePosition.split(","); //split the xy coordinates returned by previous function

      if ((positionArray[0] > dg.offsetLeft) && (positionArray[0] < dg.offsetLeft + dg.offsetWidth) && (positionArray[1] > dg.offsetTop) && (positionArray[1] < dg.offsetTop + dg.offsetHeight)) {
          var mouseOverlap = 'yes';
      } else var mouseOverlap = 'no';

      if ((divStyle.visibility === 'hidden') && (mouseOverlap === 'yes')) {
          return false;
      } else {
          document.getElementById("lefteye").style.visibility = vis1;
          document.getElementById("lefteyedes").style.visibility = vis2;
      }
  }    
</script>


<div id="lefteye" onmouseover="leftEyeVisibility('hidden', 'visible')" onmouseout="leftEyeVisibility('visible', 'hidden')">
</div>
```

With jQuery it would be much easier to do this...let me know if it works.